# How measuring the proportion of object in several classes?

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I have 4 classes and I want to classify objects in each class. I have an arbitrary number of objects indexed from $1$ to $n$.

My problem is, when $n$ varies, the proportion can change a lot. For instance:

1) if $n=1000$ I have 1st class=32%, 2nd class=18%, 3rd class=25% and 4th class=25%

2) if $n=2000$ I have 1st class=25%, 2nd class=30%, 3rd class=30% and 4th class=15%

3) if $n=3000$ I have 1st class=19%, 2nd class=25%, 3rd class=20% and 4th class=36%

With such varying proportions, what is relevant to show ? What numbers to show ? A curve ?

Thanks

Comment: Are your n observations drawn at random from the population? Or, are you only pulling the first n observations?

Comment: @JasonSanchez I'm pulling the first n observations. If I perform the measures for $n=1000$ and then for $n=2000$. The first 1000 measures are the same in both cases.

Comment: Try shuffling your dataset and repeating the analysis.

Comment: @JasonSanchez Thanks Jason, but for what reasons ?

Comment: @JasonSanchez In fact, I don't have a dataset. I have a deterministic algorithm which gives a result for a particular index of an object, and I run the program for indexes varying from $1$ to $n$.

Comment: Use n=max(n) which will give the true proportionality

Comment: Can you disclose your deterministic algorithm? Which programming frameworks do you prefer?

Comment: I can't disclose the algorithm, but I can certify you that the proportions vary all the time, for instance when $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < n_4 < n_5$. If $n_1$ is very close to $n_2$ the proportions don't vary between $n_1$ and $n_2$, but when there is a large difference, the proportions can be completely different.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep a running average of the ratio of the classes, then plot them as bands in a band plot.

[image: Example generated with SAS]

```
%let no2avg = 50;
%let noObs = 3E4;

data myRand (keep= i class);
    do i = 1 to &noObs.;
        uni = 5 * ranuni(0) - 2.5;
        if uni GT sin (i/320) + 1 then class = 3;
        else if uni GT sin (i/450) - 1 then class = 2;
        else class = 1;
        output;
    end;
run;

data myRunning;
    set myRand;
    array classes{0:%eval(&no2avg.-1)} _temporary_;
    array sum{3} _temporary_ (0,0,0);
    sum(class) = sum(class) + 1;
    if _N_ GT &no2avg. then do;
        old = classes{mod(_N_, &no2avg.)};
        sum(old) = sum(old) - 1;

        class_1 = sum{1} / &no2avg.;
        class_2 = sum{2} / &no2avg. + class_1;
    end;
    else do;
        class_1 = sum{1} / _N_;
        class_2 = sum{2} / _N_ + class_1;
    end;
    output;
    classes{mod(_N_, &no2avg.)}=class;
run;

proc sgplot data=myRunning ;
  band x=i lower=0       upper=class_1 / fillattrs=graphdata1 name='class 1' ;
  band x=i lower=class_1 upper=class_2 / fillattrs=graphdata2 name='class 2' ;
  band x=i lower=class_2 upper=1       / fillattrs=graphdata3 name='class 3' ;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 classes.
The ratio of the classes in all the samples is relatively high.
If the source of your data was [i.i.d](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables)s samples from a fixed [categorial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution), the dataset would have converge and you wouldn't have seen so distinct ratios.

Hence, it seems that the source of your samples is not iid from a fixed categorial distribution. For example, your source might be a [Markov model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_model)
In such a case, in is not always correct to talk about the ratio of the classes since its very definition might be incorrect.

If you still want to present ratios, I would have presented a range for them.
A useful range to present is the [confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval)

You can compute it as following.
Sample distinct sets, not just the first n.
It is better to take the first 1,000 samples, the next 1,000 samples and so on K times. (In general the higher the K and the samples size, the better)
Compute the mean and variance of the classes ratio and use the confidence interval formula to compute its range.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I did not understand very well. You are referering to the bar chart? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#/media/File:Confidenceinterval.png

So I will have a bar chart with 4 bars and their confidence intervals?

Comment: Is it not preferable for me to present the following king of charts?

http://www.google.fr/imgres?imgurl=http://www.emathzone.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/percentage-component-bar-chart.gif&imgrefurl=http://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/basic-statistics/percentage-component-bar-chart.html&h=291&w=588&tbnid=TelB9h7kdj1lxM:&tbnh=90&tbnw=182&usg=__TMN5RD2CFMDMALoJjdbrevWtZJk=&docid=2oAs46pZAyFeGM&sa=X&ved=0CCMQ9QEwAGoVChMIwOy8kqHzxgIVAnEUCh0RBgUC

Comment: Using a chart will make the results more readable but this is not what I tried to point out. I tried to point out that 1. Your data doesn't behaves as assumed and there for such summary might be incorrect or misleading.  2. Since the proportions differ a lot, it is better to provide a possible range and not just a number.